# can i use one google cloud load balancer for a static backend bucket AND a container deployed by cloud run? and with different ports?

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have a project that has routes and paths defined in a load balancer. Now I want to add a google cloud run container to that project. Do I need to make another load balancer, or can I add the paths to the current load balancer?

how would I add a path to the cloud run container path? (for either scenario)

like mydomain.com/"new-path/container"/"path-of-new-path"

like in load balancer paths:

/newPath/newPath/*

or /newPath

and then the container (express.js in my case) dicates the newPath -paths?

confused. Also now to add confusion to the matter. can i have two ports?

like:
mydomain.com:443/newPath:8080

Answer (score 3):

There is many possible configuration. You can route the traffic on

- The domain
- The path prefix
- A combination of both.

With Serverless NEG, you also have in addition an [URL mask](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless#using-url-mask) that you can use to route the traffic through different serverless services

If your service doesn't support the load balancer path, you can also use a [rewrite rule](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-url-rewrite) to remove that additional path level and clean the API call to your service

Finally, about the port, it's independent: the frontend ports doesn't influence the path resolution for request routing. But the domain does.

Comment: hmm ok well i need my port on the path to be 8080 for socket.io. Can I change my main domain port to that as well? is that advised. i can't change the port on the existing load balancer from 443

Comment: @TeomanKirac - what is port 8080 for? Your question states a bucket and Cloud Run. Cloud Run only supports ports 80 and 443 (80 will redirect to 443).

Comment: @JohnHanley, I understood that's the configuration of the HTTPS load balancer front end. However, I think you can't configure URL map on the port, only domain and path.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere - you are correct. I was trying to help the OP clarify what he needs to accomplish. This line will not work for Cloud Run no matter which load balancer he selects **mydomain.com:443/newPath:8080**.